# How to convert array elements to the list in output using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

Here I have some elements which are pushed into an empty array. And when I input 5 elements in the input field I get "one,two" but I want it in list.Does anybody know how to do this?

**Output:**
one,two

**Expected Ouput:**

one

two

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var arr = [];
 
  $("#txtResult").on("click", function(){
       text="";
        if (jQuery("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{5}$/, '')  )  {
                arr.push("one") ;
            }
        if ( jQuery("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{5}$/, '') )
            {
                arr.push("two")+"<br>";
            }
        if ( jQuery("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{7}$/, '') )
            {
                arr.push("three")+"<br>";
            }
        
        jQuery("p").text(arr) ;
        arr=[];
                
  });
});
    </script>
    
</head>
<body>


    <input type="text" id="txtFirstNo" name="txtFirstNo" placeholder="Enter value"  />
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="txtResult"/><br
    <p id="txtPrint" ></p>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
jQuery("p").text(arr);
```

effectively does this

```
jQuery("p").text(arr.toString());
```

And `.toString()` on an array is the same as `arr.join(",")` - if you don't want a comma but something else, then be explicit:

```
jQuery("p").html(arr.join("<br/>"));
```

(using `.html()` as it now contains html)

Updated snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arr = [];

  $("#txtResult").on("click", function() {
    text = "";
    if (jQuery("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{5}$/, '')) {
      arr.push("one");
    }
    if (jQuery("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{5}$/, '')) {
      arr.push("two");
    }
    if (jQuery("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{7}$/, '')) {
      arr.push("three")
    }

    jQuery("p").html(arr.join("<br/>"));
    arr = [];

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtFirstNo" name="txtFirstNo" placeholder="Enter value" />
<br><br>
<input type="submit" id="txtResult" /><br>
<p id="txtPrint"></p>
```

Comment: Can I able to add numbers before the output like :     
1. One
2. Two

Comment: If it's always 1.one, 2.two then just change to `arr.push("1. one")` if you mean in the order they are pushed then `arr.map((e,i) =>  (i+1) + ". " + e).join("<br/>")`